# Encoding a readable H264 4:2:2 movie by QuickTime using FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, codec

I am aware of the solution with `-pix_fmt yuv420p` as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14430593/encoding-a-readable-movie-by-quicktime-using-ffmpeg) but that encodes it at 4:2:0. I would like the encode to be a 4:2:2 and changing to `-pix_fmt yuv422p` doesn't work. I've tried different containers with out lack. What definitely works is 'prores' but I don't need such a high bitrate video.

For context, I create timelapses from photos and I would like to be able to use Quick Look or Quick Time for playback.

I use `mediainfo` to check the video's attributes.

Comment: I don't believe that QuickTime can play 4:2:2 H.264. But I don't have QT so I can't try.

Comment: It seems that you pointed me to the right direction. QuickTime [doesn't](https://forums.creativecow.net/docs/forums/post.php?forumid=20&postid=864735&univpostid=864735&pview=t) support 4:2:2 h264. 

Apple's rationale is that if you want 4:2:2 and 4:4:4 you should use ProRes. 

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question. As @llogan pointed QuickTime doesn't support h264 4:2:2. The only option is with 4:2:0 as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14430593/encoding-a-readable-movie-by-quicktime-using-ffmpeg).