# Node.js: Converting MP4 to GIF (puppeteer-lottie)

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, puppeteer

I am trying to convert a `.mp4` file to `.gif` using NPM packages, but nothing seems to be working.

I tried using [gifski](https://gif.ski/) binary package ([NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gifski)) for this, but no luck. It says its a binary package and you can use it by `child_process.spawn()` or similar. I installed it with `-g` (`global`) flag and seems like its not recognized even with `global` flag. Not sure If you can set PATH or anything. Let me know if its possible.

As for the other tries, I used [gify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gify) and its just not doing anything (no file or error).

I am getting the `.mp4` file from [puppeteer-lottie](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer-lottie) NPM package. Here's my code, if needed for testing:

```js
const renderLottie = require('puppeteer-lottie');

await renderLottie({ animationData: data, output: 'example.mp4', width: 640 });
```

`animationData`: [Sticker JSON](https://cdn.discordapp.com/stickers/754108890559283200.json)

I am pretty sure that there are much easier ways to do this, but I am just using complex ones. I just want `.mp4` to `.gif` at the end.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For those of you who are still trying to find solution, I finally found it.

We just use `ffmpeg` with `child_process.exec()`. No need to install anything.

```js
const { exec } = require("child_process");

exec("ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -qscale 0 output.gif");
```

`input` is your mp4 file that you want to convert, and `output` is your result gif file.

Source: [Conrad Lotz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12026739/18080196)